# Нахождение наибольшего числа

Tags: c

Дано задание: С клавиатуры вводятся последовательно 10 пар целых чисел x и y. В каждой паре определите максимальное число и выведите его на экран.
Я сделал вот так:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
#include <locale.h>
int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "rus");
    int x, y, n;
    n = 1;
    while (n < 10)
    {
        printf("Введите число x: \n");
        scanf_s("%d", &x);
        printf("Введите число y: \n");
        scanf_s("%d", &y);
        if (x > y)
        {
            printf("x больше y \n");
            printf("%d \n", x);
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            printf("x меньше y \n");
            printf("%d \n", y);
            break;
        }
        n == n + 1;
    }
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Но сразу после первой пары, программа вырубается. Что не так?

Comment: у вас `break` же стоит после проверки. Вот оно и рвёт цикл. Уберите его и будет вам счастье

Comment: `break` - выход из цикла... Что попросили - то и получили. Уберите его. Еще - зачем вы сравниваете `n` и `n+1` (это намек :))?  И последнее - если x не меньше y, то это еще не значит, что y больше x - они могут быть и равны.

Comment: Спасибо большое! Понял свои ошибки.